# How to force a constraint on a member's return type

Tags: f#

I am trying to force a constraint on a function such that the type of the first parameter has a member which returns `Async<'T>` as follows:

```
let inline private f (a : ^T) = (^T : (static member g : string -> ^T Async) T)
```

However, I am getting a compiler error that T is not defined. Is it possible to define a constraint in this manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a "member constraint invocation expression" and the member requires a string as its input, but you've just got an unbound identifier.  If you really want to invoke the method then just put a string in place of the identifier `T`.

If you just want to *constrain* the type parameter but not actually *invoke the member* you could do that like this:

```
let inline private f (a : ^T when ^T : (static member g : string -> ^T Async) = ...
```

but you'll need to fill in the body with something.